# Wordpress site redirects to different site when using https. Have I been hacked?

Tags: tls, wordpress, url-redirection

I own my [domain](http://nikhilbhardwaj.in) and blog infrequently, when I try to access it over https I'm first shown a warning which says that the certificate isn't trusted. This is expected as I never configured SSL for my blog, when I proceed it takes me to a random [site](https://nikhilbhardwaj.in). I've attached the screenshots as people may be hesitant to click the links.

My real blog looks like this - [image]

And over https it looks like this - [image] -

I'm baffled, does someone know how this can possibly happen. Has my site been hacked?
How can I reclaim my domain?

Comment: I had raised it on the Vlexofree forums and the moderator there has correctly configured the server now, I've also added an SSL certificate for my domain. Thanks again for helping diagnose the issue and thanks to the wonderful Vlexofree people to help resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there are other sites on the same server as your website  showing the same behaviour (like for example: http://annihilatethehero.com/ vs. https://annihilatethehero.com/) I assume you have your webspace from a shitty reseller who configured only one ssl-page on the server: The Page of the *Shanto-Mariam University of Creative Technology*

So any connection over HTTPS will lead to this page and the server doesn't even care for the domain in the request.

So I don't think your site or your domain has been hacked, it is just a misconfigured server. You can also see the page by visiting only the IP of the server with https: `https://68.168.212.202/`

Another sign for bad configuration may be the page you see when visiting the IP over http: `http://68.168.212.202/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`

> If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider: webmaster@68.168.212.202

Comment: I use Vlexofree, it's free hosting so this may very well be the case. I'll drop them an email about this. Its a relief to know that I've not been hacked.